# What is the term for 'sympathetic' when speaking of the ability to appear sympathetic rather than express sympathy?

Tags: writing

Writing a fictional story, I have this little beat:

*She found her talent there for presenting herself as sympathetic, even though it was completely uncalculated and she wasn’t consciously aware of the effect …*

The term in question is ‘sympathetic’. I’m **not** looking for a synonym. ‘Sympathetic’, referring to a person, typically means ‘one who is compassionate to the feelings of others’. That’s not what I’m trying to say.

What I am trying to say by ‘presenting herself as sympathetic’ is ‘presenting herself as someone who would likely draw sympathy’, not speaking about her capacity to express it.

So it’s the wrong word. I’m stumped. Prof. Google is, too. Can you think of a word? Or a better way to say this?

Comment: Try *pitiful,* perhaps.

Comment: How about ***pathetic***?

Comment: Needy? Wronged? I have met the nicest people who present themselves as *damsel in distress* by milking their victim status.

Comment: She has a *good bedside manner*.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a term for someone who causes others to be sympathetic towards her then

> inviting sympathy

is probably what you are looking for. Also

> the object of sympathy

for someone to whom people behave sympathetically, or for whom they have sympathy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your character is not seeking for attention (i.e. being melodramatic), I would say piteous is the word you are looking for.

Piteous [adjective]

> Of a kind to move to pity or compassion.

[Link to definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/piteous)

Comment: Please add a reference to a dictionary definition or two and correct your spelling mistake. Also it's either "looking for" or "seeking" without "for".